# How to remove characters from a string

Tags: bash, shell, key-value

How to remove characters from a string like this

"i have string  in a variable say string="auto.deploy.active = yes", i want to take out everything after "=" and store that extracted string in another variable using a shell script"

Comment: Is the string inside a file, pipe, or variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash and Parameter Expansion:

```
string="auto.deploy.active = yes"
value="${string#*= }"
```

Comment: if i want to take out everything before = and store it in a variable

Comment: Use `key="${string% =*}"`

Comment: Thanks cyrus, it did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`

command is:

```
$ var1=`echo "auto.deploy.active = yes" | awk -F"=" '{print $1}'` ; echo $var1
auto.deploy.active 

$ var2=`echo "auto.deploy.active = yes" | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'` ; echo $var2
yes
```

Comment: how to store this result in another variable

Comment: Please search before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash

Comment: check the updated answer @JamesTaylor

Comment: I suggest to use `-F " = "`.